# Example $p(z),q(z)$ analytic at $z_0$ but $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ not m-th order pole at $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Give an example of functions $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ analytic at $z_0$ and where $z_0$ is an m-th order zero of $q(z)$ but $f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ does not have an m-th order pole at $z_0$. Explain.

does my example work?

example:

$p(z) = (z-i), q(z)= (z+i)$ Both analytic at $z_0 = -i$. $z_0$ is a 1st order zero of $q(z)$. $f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}= \frac{(z-i)}{(z+i)}$ is not analytic at $z_0 = -i$. Does $f(z)$ have a 1st order pole at $z_0$?

Comment: No. Your example does not works. $-i$ is a pole for your $f(z)$.  Use $p(z)=z^2+1$.

Comment: Why not $\,p(z)=q(z)\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(z) = q(z) = z$. Then $f(z) = 1$.